# SQL - Order by the numbers of rows?

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

So I have a table with 5 columns: `id, user_id, news_id, comment and date`. Every time a user posts something on the news's comment area the data is inserted into this table.

Now I am trying to make a top poster function that will display the people with the mosts comments posted.

I would like to know how to order the result from this table based on how many times that user_id is present in the table.

For example:

```
1 - 134(user_id) -> 20 posts(that's how many times this user_id was found in the table.)
2 - 123 -> 19
3 - 168 -> 15
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT (*) as comments
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY comments DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

TSQL

```
    select userID, count(*) 
    from userIDtable 
    group by userID 
    order by count(*) desc, userID asc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing rows with columns, but never mind.  This is easy to do:

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   COUNT(*) posts
FROM
   comments
GROUP BY
   user_id
ORDER BY
   posts DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(user_id) C, user_id FROM RECORDS ORDER BY C LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

"So I have a table with 5 rows: id, user_id, news_id, comment and date. Every time a user posts something on the news's comment area the data is inserted into this table. "
In this answer I'll assume you have meant 5 columns above.

```
select user_id, count(*) num from tableName group by user_id order by num desc;
```